# Communicate b/w two components in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have two `qml` files i.e. `main.qml` & `myComponent.qml`

The `main.qml` invoke `myComponent.qml` like below:-

```
onTriggered: {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("myComponent.qml")
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        .
        .
        .
        var window = component.createObject(root)

        if (window !== null){
            window.show()
        } 
        else {
            console.error("Error creating window object")
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Error loading component:", component.errorString())
    }
}
```

I've also defined `Connections` within the `main.qml` file to receive latest data from `c++` like below:-

```
Connections {
    target: myObject  // C++ object exposed to qml
    function onSignalRecv(response) {
        console.log(response)  // Here i'm getting the latest data
    }
}
```

Now i want to transfer this latest data from `main.qml` to `myComponent.qml`. Every time I receive data in onSignalRecv(..) i want to transfer it.

The `myComponent.qml` contains a `ListView` to show updated data and i want to update the data in realtime.

Comment: You can make Connections section in myComponent.qml as well

Comment: The generalized solution is to create a model, and give that to all components which need the data.